# Two actionButtons in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny function which contains two actionButtons. These two are left and right buttons which help the plot to shift when clicked. Both buttons work OK when they were first clicked. The problem occurs when I re-click them. It will bounce back and forth between two ranges no matter which button I click. I guess it might be the problem that "right" and "left" button do not return to 0 after clicked. What will be an alternative way to solve my question? Thanks ahead!

My code is below:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("test", label="test", min=0, max=1808, value=c(0,50)),
  actionButton("left", "Left"),
  actionButton("right", "Right")

),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("bar")
)
)
))


shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
observe({
if(input$right){
  isolate({
    if(input$test[2]+ round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2) <= 1808)
    updateSliderInput(session, "test", value=c(input$test[1] + round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2), input$test[2] + round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2)))
})
}
if (input$left){
  isolate({
    if(input$test[1] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2) > 0)
    updateSliderInput(session, "test", value=c(input$test[1] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2), input$test[2] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2)))
})      
}
})

subdata <- reactive({
  sub.data <- data[input$test[1]:input$test[2]]
})

output$bar <- renderPlot({
  barplot(subdata())
})  

})
```

Comment: Your guess is right. the problem is due to the fact that action buttons never reset. Can you please provide the `data` in your code above so I have a full reproducible example to work with? I think I can propose a solution but first I will need to see the `data` variable.

Comment: You can use any data for a bar plot. Just generate some uniform data, for example, data <- runif(1808)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using two `observe` expression, one for each button.

```
observe({
  if(input$right){
    isolate({
        if(input$test[2]+ round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2) <= 1808)
          updateSliderInput(session, "test", value=c(input$test[1] + round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2), input$test[2] + round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2)))
      })
    }
})

observe({
  if(input$left){ 
    isolate({
        if(input$test[1] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2) > 0)
          updateSliderInput(session, "test", value=c(input$test[1] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2), input$test[2] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2)))
      }) 
  }
})
```

Each button will then only be triggered when it is clicked on and you won't need to reset the value of the buttons.

Answer (score 4):

In shiny 0.11 there was really nice update for eventhandling, which streamline use of actionButton greatly. Now you can use `observeEvent()` for this kind of tasks where you want to perform function in response of event(eg. pressing of `actionButton`)

Minimal working example(requires shiny version 0.11):

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$left, function() {
        if(input$test[2]+ round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2) <= 1808)
        updateSliderInput(session, "test", value=c(input$test[1] + round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2), input$test[2] + round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2)))
    }

    )
    observeEvent(input$right, function() {
         if(input$test[1] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2) > 0)
    updateSliderInput(session, "test", value=c(input$test[1] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2), input$test[2] - round((input$test[2]-input$test[1])/2)))
    }
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("test", label="test", min=0, max=1808, value=c(0,50)),
      actionButton("left", "Left"),
      actionButton("right", "Right")
    ),
    mainPanel(


    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```