# eventReactive two action buttons Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to trigger different function on the same output with two action buttons.
`interests_data` and `interests_data_refresh` are eventReactive depending on two different output.

Isolate may not take more than one action button. I tried to keep track on the first input but I'm afraid refreshing the page may cause problem on the tracking. I haven't seen any example about how to do this problem ie having different behavior on the same output depending on the button pressed. Here is my attempt :

```
output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
input$insert
input$delete
isolate({
  if (input$insert == 0) {
    start_interests <- dbReadTable(db, "Interests")
    DT::datatable(start_interests[],
                  options = list(
                    lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200),
                    order = list(list(7, 'desc')),
                    pageLength = 25
                  ))
  }
  else if (input$insert == x+1) {
    #updated_interests()
    DT::datatable(interests_data(),
                  options = list(
                    lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200),
                    order = list(list(7, 'desc')),
                    pageLength = 25
                  ))
  }
    else {
      DT::datatable(interests_data_refresh(),
                    options = list(
                      lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200),
                      order = list(list(7, 'desc')),
                      pageLength = 25
                    ))
    }
    x <<- as.numeric(input$insert)
})
```

})

Comment: I wonder if two eventReactive each nested inside one observe() observing each of the the action button will do the job. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948623/two-actionbuttons-in-shiny

Comment: Ok it works with two eventReactive assigning on one unique global function each nested inside one observe() observing each of the the action button. Isolate therefore only needs if and else.

Comment: Could you please post your working solution?

Comment: I have a someone similar question if anyone wants to take a stab at it. I'm really stuck with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329078/text-input-with-action-button